# How to highlight Google Sheets Tab based on Day of the week

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get the specific tab corresponding to the Day of the week to highlight based on which day of the week it is. I have only Monday - Friday, and I am using the WEEKDAY attribute to get the day of the week in number format then converting to `dddd` Full weekday name format. Not I also want this to be checked when the sheet is opened for the day. Below is the code I have, however, I am not able to get any tab to highlight.

```
function onOpen(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var Master = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
var Monday = ss.getSheetByName("Monday");
var Tuesday = ss.getSheetByName("Tuesday");
var Wednesday = ss.getSheetByName("Wednesday");
var Thursday = ss.getSheetByName("Thursday");
var Friday = ss.getSheetByName("Friday");
var highlight = ss.getRange("E1");
 if (highlight == "Monday") {
Monday.setTabColor("ff0000");
 }
 if (highlight == "Tuesday") {
Tuesday.setTabColor("ff0000");
 }
 if (highlight == "Wednesday") {
Wednesday.setTabColor("ff0000");
 }
 if (highlight == "Thursday") {
Thursday.setTabColor("ff0000");
 }
 if (highlight == "Friday") {
Friday.setTabColor("ff0000");
 }
}
```

E1 is the current cell that the spelled-out weekday is in. Any help shedding some light on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost working. You don't store the value, just the range of the cell. Modify:

```
function onOpen(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var Master = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
var Monday = ss.getSheetByName("Monday");
var Tuesday = ss.getSheetByName("Tuesday");
var Wednesday = ss.getSheetByName("Wednesday");
var Thursday = ss.getSheetByName("Thursday");
var Friday = ss.getSheetByName("Friday");
var highlight = ss.getRange("E1").getValue();
Logger.log(highlight);
 if (highlight == "Monday") {
Monday.setTabColor("ff0000");
 }
 if (highlight == "Tuesday") {
Tuesday.setTabColor("ff0000");
 }
 if (highlight == "Wednesday") {
Wednesday.setTabColor("ff0000");
 }
 if (highlight == "Thursday") {
Thursday.setTabColor("ff0000");
 }
 if (highlight == "Friday") {
Friday.setTabColor("ff0000");
 }
}
```

Use the Logger.log(highlight) to see what value you get in the protocol, to debug your code. You can delete or comment this line in production.